# Is it a good idea to drink whey protein before going out to gym?

Tags: workout, nutrition

Is it a good idea if I have my whey protein before I go out to workout in the morning (around 7am)?

From my place to gym is around 40 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing in particular regarding the timing of your protein consumption that will make any significant difference according to our current understanding. Keep in mind however, that some people experience minor gastric distress from whey protein and this could interfere with training.

(Farts. I'm talking about farts.)

Answer (score 2):

#### How important is nutrient or meal timing?

Under most circumstances and in the grand scheme of things, it's not critical. Of far greater importance is hitting your calorie, macro- and micro-nutrient needs over the course of the day. After that, consistency and commitment should be applied to an appropriate workout plan that suits your performance and/or body goals. If you tend to train in a fasted state, getting your post-workout nutrition in as soon as possible is a good idea, but the first two points (daily diet goals, consistent training) still take precedence.

For a good paper reviewing the literature examining the ideas and research behind nutrient timing and the "post-workout window", check out [this meta-review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3577439/pdf/1550-2783-10-5.pdf).

For a review specific to protein timing and it's effect on strength and muscle building, check out [this review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3879660/).

Answer (score 1):

First lets set aside that you haven't shared your goals and have in mind that a pre-workout whey protein shake can't fix general poor or low protein diet.

The important part for me here is that you are working out early in the morning, after not having consumed any protein (or food) for a long period of time. Your insulin levels are low, cortisol is high - this is not optimal environment for weightlifting. So yes, drinking whey protein before going to the gym is a good idea. Make sure to also consume some carbohydrates as well. Easily processed fruit like banana or handful of raisins will do just fine. Most importantly - don't weightlift in the morning in fasted state.

Here are some articles with decent amount of medical research references that could help you figure it out (leave aside promoted specific proprietary products in the articles):
https://www.t-nation.com/supplements/top-10-post-workout-nutrition-myths
https://www.t-nation.com/supplements/post-workout-nutrition-is-dead